# MATLAB function fminunc

Tags: matlab

```
x0 = [-1,2,1,2];
fun = @rosenbrockwithgrad;

x= fminunc(fun,x0)


function [f] = rosenbrockwithgrad(x,r)
in = inp();
% Calculate objective f
f =  r+(rose(1,2,x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),in.ep)+(1-x(1))^2);


end

function [f1] = rose(m,l,k1,k2,k3,k4,ep)

f1=(100*(k1 - k2)^2)+ep+(k3*l)+(k4*m);
end
```

Input functions

```
function [in] = inp()

in.ep=-2;

end
```

The above is a code to find the minimum of the function 'rosenbrockwithgrad'. The code works perfectly and return the minimum when there is no variable 'r'. But I need that r and it is a vector. How to sort this issue?

Comment: just use `x(5)` instead of `r` and add a corresponding initial guess at the end of your `x0` (and then remove `r` as an input)?

Comment: Noticed that `fminunc` is able to return a local minimum, it does not guarantee that this local minimum is also the absolute minimum.